# Unique column by foreign key but seems to duplicate purpose of another table. Is this the idomatic way of doing it?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, normalization

Given the following model where we have a menu that contains multiple categories

```
Menu *-- Categories

Menu A 
  - Category 1
  - Category 2
  - Category 3
Menu B
  - Category blah
  - Category 1
  - Category 2
```

As such in the database

```
CREATE TABLE menus (
  id UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE categories (
  id      BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name    VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE menu_category_members (
  menu_id          UUID NOT NULL REFERENCES menus(id),
  category_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES categories(id),
  UNIQUE(menu_id, category_id)
);

// Menu
| id | name   |
| 1  | Menu A |
| 2  | Menu B |

// Category
| id | name          |
| 1  | Category 1    |
| 2  | Category 2    |
| 3  | Category 3    |
| 4  | Category blah |
| 5  | Category 1    |
| 6  | Category 2    |

// Category members
| menu_id | category_id |
| 1       | 1           |
| 1       | 2           |
| 1       | 3           |
| 2       | 4           |
| 2       | 5           |
| 2       | 6           |
```

I want to ensure that `categories.name` is unique per menu i.e. no duplicate categories in a menu

1. Is it as simple as including `menu_id` as FK in `categories` and adding unique constraint like below?
2. Isn't this duplicating the purpose of `menu_category_members` table making the table redundant?

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
  id      BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name    VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  menu_id UUID NOT NULL REFERENCES menus(id),
  UNIQUE(name, menu_id)
);
```

Comment: How about `menus(id, category_id(FK))--> categories(id, name)` with `UNIQUE(id, category_id)` on `menus`?

Comment: That's missing a lot of necessary details. How are menus and categories related to each other? Like can a menu be in multiple categories? Can a category have multiple menus? Does a menu need to belong to at least one category? Does a category have at least one menu? Etc.?

Comment: Thanks @stickybit . I have edited the question to clarify the relationship

Comment: If name is unique per menu then menu is unique in _members. (That implies menu-name pairs are unique, supersets of unique are unique.)

Comment: @philipxy Yes menu - category pairs are unique, however that does not enforce that 2 categories that have same menu id, to have unique names

Comment: If a category cannot belong to more than one menu (and different categories can share a name), then yes, there's no need for a linking table like `menu_category_members` and your changes to `categories` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you should simplify the structure which is best practice in dynamic Menu implementation.

Pls see below structure

```
// Menu
| id | name   |
| 1  | Menu A |
| 2  | Menu B |

// Category
| id | name          |parent_menu_id
| 1  | Category 1    |1
| 2  | Category 2    |1
| 3  | Category 3    |1
| 4  | Category blah |2
| 5  | Category 1    |2
| 6  | Category 2    |2
```

Then you can implement Unique key constraint on parent_menu_id and name as below

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
  id      BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name    VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
  parent_menu_id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT uc_category UNIQUE (parent_menu_id,name)
);
```